# Java Hibernate CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE without update

Tags: java, hibernate, save, cascade

I'm trying to save a model with libraries that are stored in cascade. In the model we use the following notation for it:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "name_table_column")
@Cascade (CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
```

This means that when saving the model, insert or update these libraries according the libraries exist or not. In this case we just wanted to perform the inserts and ignore all the updates. Is there any way for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for [CascadeType.PERSIST](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/metamodel/binding/CascadeType.html#PERSIST):

> CascadeType.PERSIST: cascades the persist (create) operation to
>   associated entities persist() is called or if the entity is managed